# How to play video stream with MPMoviePlayerController in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, stream, media-player, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am trying to play a video stream from the internet on the iPhone by pressing a button.
I used many code samples but nothing worked. With this code it opens a black view without any video stream or controls in it. (The stream itself works.)

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://MyStreamURL.com"];
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:moviePlayer];

moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
[moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Instead of creating a `MPMoviePlayerController` and adding that to your view, it is probably simpler to create a `MPMoviePlayerViewController` and present that view controller modally (since you are trying to show your video full screen anyway).  Then the MPMoviePlayerViewController can manage the presentation of your video for you.

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *mpvc = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                     selector:@selector(moviePlaybackDidFinish:)
                                         name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                       object:nil];    

mpvc.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;

[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mpvc];
[mpvc release];
```

In your `moviePlayBackDidFinish` delegate method you can then dismiss the model view controller.

Comment: Small correction though; you are supposed to use `presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated` instead of `presentModalViewController`. This will result into the proper animation effect users are expecting from a movie player.

Comment: Thanks @Till, I did not know that.  I have edited my code sample to reflect this change.

Comment: But why exactly doesn't the approach above with MPMoviePlayerController work?

Comment: @alper, it is because moviePlayer is not retained. At least it is true in my project.

Answer (score 2):

Need to mention movie source type as streaming

```
moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
```

Answer (score 1):

Add AVFoundation frame work in Link Libraries section

In your .h file add

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
@interface video_liveViewController : UIViewController<MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate,MPMediaPlayback>
```

In your .m file

```
NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://172.31.17.252:1935/live/myStream/playlist.m3u8"];
movieController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:movieController];
[movieController.moviePlayer play];
```

Answer (score -1):

just add "`MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming`" to "`moviesourcetype`"