# iOS : Playing remote video with URL with MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, mpmovieplayercontroller

```
NSURL *url= [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x109z02"];
MPMoviePlayerController  *theMoviPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
theMoviPlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeFill;
theMoviPlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 60, 320, 350);
[self.view addSubview:theMoviPlayer.view];
[self.theMoviPlayer play];
```

framework is also addded and imported in .h file but video is not playing in iphone (internet connection is also ok)

Comment: This is happening normally in new xcode.
Try creating the property of Video Player and using the property will work fine.

I was facing the problem earlier,by googling I found this answer and it works for me. You should give it a try.

Comment: i  have created proprty too, but doesnt work for me

Comment: check this following link it may help you :::: [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8864405/play-video-stream-with-mpmovieplayercontroller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSURL *url   = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.ebookfrenzy.com/ios_book/movie/movie.mov"];
_moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                                          initWithContentURL:url];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                      selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                      name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                      object:_moviePlayer];

_moviePlayer.controlStyle   = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
_moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
[self.view addSubview:_moviePlayer.view];
[_moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `UIWebView` , a very simple and easy way.