# Playing movie downloaded with FTP in iOS

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have an application that downloads movies from an ftp-server and then plays them with an MPMoviePlayerController. However the movieplayer fails with MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackError.

the code looks like this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[contents objectAtIndex:index]];
NSLog(@"url: %@",url);

self.movieController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
```

the nslog gives this answer:

url: file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/E8C9DFE8-9802-4EC1-B560-3EEE96E0AF5E/Documents/media/testfilm.mov

Does anybody have an idea on how to get the movie to play? If I add the movie to the project and use the following code the movie works.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"testfilm" ofType:@"mov"]];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [play video stream with MPMoviePlayerController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8864405/play-video-stream-with-mpmovieplayercontroller)

Comment: I have read that question and I don't think it concerns my issue because that question is about remote files.

Comment: Alright, so quick and easy test, does the file at `file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/E8C9DFE8-9802-4EC1-B560-3EEE96E0AF5E/Documents/media/testfilm.mov` actually exist? Can you play it in another app?

Comment: I solved the problem, the file was corrupt, the code was correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `fileURLWithPath:` for a remote file, that is wrong.

Use `URLWithString:` for remote files instead.

---

See the [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html) on that exact subject - particularly the parameters section;

`URLWithString:`

Creates and returns an NSURL object initialized with a provided string.

`+ (id)URLWithString:(NSString *)URLString`

**Parameters**

*URLString*

The string with which to initialize the NSURL object. Must be a URL that conforms to RFC 2396. This method parses URLString according to RFCs 1738 and 1808. (To create NSURL objects for file system paths, use `fileURLWithPath:isDirectory:` instead.)
Return Value
An NSURL object initialized with URLString. If the string was malformed, returns nil.

**Discussion**

This method expects URLString to contain any necessary percent escape codes, which are ‘:’, ‘/’, ‘%’, ‘#’, ‘;’, and ‘@’. Note that ‘%’ escapes are translated via UTF-8.

Comment: I'm sorry if I didn't make myself clear. What i meant is that the file is downloaded to the Documents directory for later use. Therefore it should be considered as a local file, or am I wrong?

Comment: are you sure that movie is properly playable. You could export your documents folder (using the Apple iPhone Configuration Utility) and try to play it on your desktop using Quicktime or alike.

Comment: Thank you, I checked the file in the simulator and it would not play on my computer either. The file size was only a third of the actual size so something must be going wrong while downloading the file. That is weird though because all PDF-files downloads properly.