# MPMoviePlayerController won't play the Video

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

This is my code. I want to play one video which is present in the device memory. The video format is .mov. But I only got the black screen.

```
NSString *documentdir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
        NSString *tileDirectory = [documentdir stringByAppendingPathComponent:urlpath];
        self.videoPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:tileDirectory]];
        [self.videoPlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 420)];

        [self.videoPlayer prepareToPlay];
        [self.view addSubview:self.videoPlayer.view];
        [self.videoPlayer play];
```

Comment: Can you post further code.

Comment: @JohnWoods: This is only the code for MPMoviePlayerController. I am capture the screen and make video. After stop recording I save the video in local memory of device. Now I m testing in simulator. So After finish recording I search that Url there is one video It run perfectly. But I try to show video by MPMoviePlayerController it show only black screen

Comment: OK, so you know the video is recorded correctly? --- Where are you executing the above code? In your ViewController? If so in which method? is your videoPlayer an ivar?

Comment: @JohnWoods: Yes videoPlayer I declared as ivar. I have an delegate in screenMakerController. I pass the file name in finishWritingWithCompletionHandler block.

Comment: Can you as a test, try to make a quick blank template with the above code? It will work IMO. I think you have an issue when passing the file.

Comment: @JohnWoods:Can't understand what you are telling. Can you please tell briefly

Comment: @JohnWoods: I found my error. It captures the screen and makes the video. But I can see the video of the content of url, when my app closed and while reopen I hardcore the videoUrl it works perfectly. Now how can I solve my problem. I have no idea about it.. Please tell what to do now?

Answer (score 0):

I got my output. I refer this link:[How to play video stream with MPMoviePlayerController in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8864405/play-video-stream-with-mpmovieplayercontroller) to solve my problem.

My modified code below..

```
self.videoPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlpath]];
    self.videoPlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
    [self.videoPlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 420)];
    [self.view addSubview: self.videoPlayer.view];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlaybackDidFinish:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:nil];
    [self.videoPlayer.backgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [self.videoPlayer play];
```

This line is the key.. `self.videoPlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;`

Comment: That is bizarre and sounds very much like a bug. You are incorrectly identifying the local movie file as being a remote stream - if that really fixed your issue, you should file a bug report at Apple!

Comment: @Till: In ios7 it works but other it not work. How to play an local movie file. Can you please tell

Comment: Make sure you try it with content that is fully compatible with iOS. Try a different video and see if that makes any change. And do not identify the content as being a stream when it is not.