# MPMoviePlayerViewController Not playing video by streaming?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, mpmovieplayer

I am using the below code to play the video, but its working fine while using the local url that mean resourse file path. Not working for server url.

```
player = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:urlvalue];
player.view.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 800, 800);
player.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay=YES;

player.moviePlayer.movieSourceType= MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
[player.moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleDefault];

[self.view addSubview:player.view];
[player.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
[player.moviePlayer play];
```

Kindly correct me if I missed out something. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to present MPMoviePlayerViewContoller modally; check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/8864540

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention on iOS 9 App transport security. If you haven't set it up, streaming will fail with black empty screen.

Comment: Thanks, I had missed that!

Answer (score 0):

Change `movieSourceType` from `File` to `Streaming` :

```
player.moviePlayer.movieSourceType= MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
```

Note : `url` should be a `streaming url` not `physical file path`

Comment: already I tried out this player.moviePlayer.movieSourceType= MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming; not working