# Displaying and playing youtube videos without using Youtube API

Tags: ios, ios7, video-streaming

I want to display and play youtube videos . It would be better for me if there is any solution without using the youtube API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried in a different way without the Youtube API and it worked for me . You can add these bunch of codes in the implementation file. And I hope it will work for you

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];
 NSString *html = @"\
<html><head>\
<style type=\"text/css\">\
body {    background-color: transparent;\
color: white; \
}\
</style>\
</head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
<iframe class=\"youtube-player\" width=\"300\" height=\"300\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/5hyy2JfuXko\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen=\"true\"></iframe>\
</body></html>";

UIWebView *videoView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 80.0, 300.0, 300.0)];
videoView.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
videoView.scrollView.bounces=NO;
[videoView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
[self.view addSubview:videoView];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Using the embed code would work! But i dont really know where you would want to play this video. If you are doing this in HTML then it would work, if you are using objective c for say iOS development, you can use the MPMoviePlayer to play the youtube link.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com/embed/5hyy2JfuXko"];
MPMoviePlayerViewController *mpvc = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                     selector:@selector(moviePlaybackDidFinish:)
                                         name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                       object:nil];    

mpvc.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;

[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mpvc];
```

As shown here
[How to play video stream with MPMoviePlayerController in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8864405/how-to-play-video-stream-with-mpmovieplayercontroller-in-ios)

Comment: I think using the MPMoviePlayerViewController as opposed to using raw html and displaying on a webview is better as you would have better control.